# A Schwartz function is measurable

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, schwartz-space

prove in details that if $f \in \mathcal{S}$ (a Schwartz function) where$$ 
\mathcal{S}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right):=\left\{f \in C^{\infty}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right): \forall \alpha \in \mathbb{N}_{0}^{n}, \forall k \in \mathbb{N}_{0}:|x|^{k}\left|\partial^{\alpha} f(x)\right| \lesssim 1 \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}\right\}
$$
then $f$ is measurable (i.e. $\left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}: f(x)<a\right\}$ is measurable)

Does it follows  directly since $f$ is continuous (and thus measurable)? or maybe it stems from the fact that $f$ decays faster than any inverse polynom?

Comment: Sure, continuity immediately implies that that set is measurable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, measurability of $f$ follows directly from its continuity.